# Use a relationship to filter data in power BI

Tags: relationship, visualization, powerbi

I am working with a clustered bar chart that is influenced by a relationship to another table. When data is selected in that table I get the following result:

[image: Default power bi clustered bar chart]

The dark green being the data that matches the relationship and the light green being the whole data set.

However, because sometimes the bars are very small, I would like to have the bar chart adjust to only include the data from the current selected relationship, as shown below.

[image: Filtered power bi clustered bar chart]

Is there a way to limit the chart to only the data relevant to the current relationship? Alternatively, is there a way to filter out all values that are zero from the current relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to click on the chart, go to the format tab, click on "edit interactions", and then click on the little filter icon at the top.

[image]